# How to use apply function in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

So i have a dataframe like this and i am trying to check correlation between the columns with isbigger  function which controls the values.

```
df = pd.read_csv('2020.csv')

def isbigger(x):
if x > 7:
    return True
return False
```

It works fine with when i pass in a single column name like

```
df['Ladder score'].apply(isbigger)
```

However when i get theese dataframe's correlation and try to apply it does not works like this

```
df.drop(axis=1,columns = ['Country name','Regional indicator']).apply(isbigger).corr(method = 'spearman')
```

I did even dropped the string columns but not still works, how can i apply an entire dataframe ?

Comment: *but not still works*, probably you should include the error you received.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `apply`, just use the usual boolean operators here:

```
df.drop(['Country name', 'Regional indicator'], axis=1).gt(7).corr()
```

Comment: What does .gt(7) do?

Comment: @Riptide `gt` stands for `greater than`.

Comment: @niimet must be *less than or equal to*, or `le` for short :-)

Comment: so what is the opposite of greater than, then. And the other question how can i apply an entire dataframe, think it as if i want to change the values.

Comment: @niimet what I wrote there is applied to the entire data frame already.

Answer (score 0):

The `apply()` function is used to invoke a python function on values of Series.

Syntax:

```py
Series.apply(self, func, convert_dtype=True, args=(), **kwds)
```